# Python lists get specific length of elements from index

Tags: python, string, list

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
```

I need to obtain a specific length of elements form a list starting at a specific index in Python. For instance I would like to get the three next elements from the `[2]` element above. Is there anyway to get the three elements from the specific index? I wont always know the next amount of elements I want to get, sometimes I may want to get two elements, sometimes eight elements, so x elements.

I know I can do `my_list[2:]` to get all of the elements from the third element to the end of the list. What I want to do is specify how many elements to read after the third element. Conceptually in my mind the example above would look like `my_list[2:+3]` however I know this wont work.

How can I achieve this or is it better to define my own function to give me this functionality?

Answer (score 4):

You are actually very close:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
>>> x = 3
>>> my_list[2:2+x]
[3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

As you can see, the answer to your question is to slice the list.

The syntax for slicing is `list[start:stop:step]`.  `start` is where to begin, `stop` is where to end, and `step` is what to count by (I didn't use step in my answer).

Comment: ty - @iCodez for the link on your profile to "Laws of Software Development" - I realize this has nothing to do with your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you should simply use

```
my_list[2:2+3]
```

and in general

```
list[ STARTING_INDEX : END_INDEX ]
```

which is equivalent to

```
list[ STARTING_INDEX : STARTING_INDEX + LENGTH ]




>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
>>> my_list[2:3]
[3]
>>> my_list[2:2+3]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: In general `[START_INDEX : END_INDEX : STEP]`. And all of them can also be negative or can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
n = 3
print my_list[2:2+n]
```

Nothing smart here. But, you can pull `n` out and tweak it the way you want.